# transparent on simulator but not device

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I have been working on this app, and its already summited to the app store but I recently am updating the whole UI and look of the app for iOS 7. So i changed the whole top bar from a toolbar to a UINavigationBar and changed the color in AppDelegate.m with,

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:UIColorFromRGB(0x4296BA)];
```

and changed the font color with,

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes: [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                                       [UIColor colorWithRed:255.0/255.0 green:245.0/255.0 blue:255.0/255.0 alpha:1.0], NSForegroundColorAttributeName, nil]];
```

and everything works fine, the bar color changes, the font changes, and its transparent when scrolling down at least it is on the simulator, but when i plug my device in a run it i dont see the transparency? Ive tried this as well in the AppDelegate.m,

```
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTranslucent:YES];
```

but when i run the application it crashes on both the simulator or the device with this,

```
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
```

Does anyone know how i can fix this?

Comment: What iOS device are you using? Not all support the transparency you see in the simulator.

Comment: No it works in the simulator but not on the device. Its an iPhone 5s

Comment: Yes, that's what I said. Though the 5s should be showing transparency.

Comment: @rmaddy Ok i think the problem is, i paid really close attention to it and i can see the transparancy but only in the dock (where the tabs of the app are) but not on the top navigation bar, but i also noticed that in the dock the transparency is really low, you can barely notice it.

Comment: Is there a way to boost the transparency?